Centering text above matrix in amsmath
I'm relatively new to using latex and I've been trying to center text (as a label) above a matrix and am using \array to put a label above a matrix, I've written it out this
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        & \\ \text{Matrix Label } A \\
        \newcommand{\zm}{%
            \begin{pmatrix}
                2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
                6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
                10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
                14 & 15 & 16 & 17
            \end{pmatrix}%
        }
        \left.
        \,\smash[b]{\underbrace{\!\zm\!}_{\textstyle\text{$n$}}}\,
        \right\}\text{$m$}
        \vphantom{\underbrace{\zm}_{\text{$n$}}}
    \end{array} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}

The output of this ends up looking like this, where the text is centered above everything including the braces,

However, I'm trying to make the output look more like this:

How can I get the text to be centered above the matrix?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

The nicematrix package might make this easier.

Here are a couple of options using an array to place the matrix elements. The first option sticks to using a pmatrix, while the second constructs the matrix via an additional array. It all depends on what you're preference for the column count \underbrace should be.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
  \newcommand{\zm}{\begin{pmatrix}
     2 &  3 &  4 &  5 \\
     6 &  7 &  8 &  9 \\
    10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    14 & 15 & 16 & 17
  \end{pmatrix}}
  \begin{array}{ @{} c @{} l @{} }
    \text{Matrix label } A \\
    \underbrace{\zm}_{n} &
      \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
      \vphantom{\zm}
      \right\} \scriptstyle m
  \end{array}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\[
  \newcommand{\zm}{\begin{array}{@{} *{4}{c} @{} }
     2 &  3 &  4 &  5 \\
     6 &  7 &  8 &  9 \\
    10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
    14 & 15 & 16 & 17
  \end{array}}
  \begin{array}{ @{} r @{} c @{} l @{} }
    & \text{Matrix label } A \\
    \left(
      \vphantom{\zm}
    \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace &
      \underbrace{\zm}_{n} &
      \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
        \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
          \vphantom{\zm}
        \right)
      \right\} \scriptstyle m
  \end{array}
\]
\lipsum[3][1-4]


\end{document}


With {NiceMatrix} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}[first-row]
\Block{1-4}{\text{Matrix label $A$}} \\
  2  & 3  & 4  & 5 & & \Block{4-1}{n} \\
  6  & 7  & 8  & 9 \\
  10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
  14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\
\\
\\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix({1-1}{4-4})  % the main parenthesis
  \UnderBrace[shorten,yshift=1mm]{4-1}{4-4}{n}  % the brace under the matrix
  \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{4-4}{\}}[xshift=2.5mm]     % the brace on the right
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}


